# Prevent Duplicate UltiSnips Matching

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I have two UltiSnips triggers defined that are matching in one particular way that I want to prevent. The first trigger is defined as this:

```
snippet "exa(ct)?" "Exact" r
```

The second like this:

```
snippet "getct|ct" "Get( CurrentTime )" rw
```

Typing `exact<tab>` gives me UltiSnips' choice message to select one of the above. Shouldn't the `w` option at the end of the second snippet prevent it from firing unless it's surrounded by non-word characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use `\b` at the beginning of the regular expressions and forego the `w` option, as `r` always overrides the other options.

```
snippet "\bexa(ct)?" "Exact" r
...
snippet "\bgetct|ct" "Get( CurrentTime )" r
```